# Why does Jay from Ninjago have a scar?

Tags: minifigures, ninjago

Jay, one of the protagonists of the Ninjago series, has a scar on his face. I would like someone to let me know what this is about.

Comment: Great question, and welcome to LEGO Answers!

Answer (score 6):

According to the book, *LEGO NINJAGO: The Visual Dictionary (Masters of Spinjitzu)*:

> Eyebrow notch caused by an explosion

The relevant page can be previewed on [the Amazon page for the book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1465422994):

[image: page image]